# MongoDB list available databases in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

I am writing an algorithm that will go thru all available Mongo databases in java.

On the windows shell I just do

```
show dbs
```

How can I do that in java and get back a list of all the available databases?

Comment: Are you using the standard driver ?

Comment: Yes i am using the standard one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You would do this like so:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
List<String> dbs = mongoClient.getDatabaseNames();
```

That will simply give you a list of all of the database names available.

You can see the documentation [here](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#getDatabaseNames()).

**Update:**

As @CydrickT mentioned below, `getDatabaseNames` is already deprecated, so we need switch to:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoCursor<String> dbsCursor = mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().iterator();
while(dbsCursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(dbsCursor.next());
}
```

Comment: How did i miss that ! Yea that did the trick ! thank you loads !

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who comes here because the method `getDatabaseNames();` is deprecated / not available, here is the new way to get this information:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoCursor<String> dbsCursor = mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().iterator();
while(dbsCursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(dbsCursor.next());
}
```

Here is a method that returns the list of database names like the previous `getDatabaseNames()` method:

```
public List<String> getDatabaseNames(){
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(); //Maybe replace it with an already existing client
    List<String> dbs = new ArrayList<String>();
    MongoCursor<String> dbsCursor = mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().iterator();
    while(dbsCursor.hasNext()) {
        dbs.add(dbsCursor.next());
    }
    return dbs;
}
```

Comment: This is true,thanks so much for the answer ,this should be the correct answer so there will be no confusion.Cheers,best of luck.